# Laravel lockforupdate misunderstanding SELECTS

Tags: mysql, database, concurrency, laravel-4, transactions

Simple question.

If I'm using DB::transactions() and I do the following:

```
DB::transaction(function()
{
  $result = 
    DB::table('orders')->select('id')->where('id', '>', 17)->lockForUpdate()->get();
});
```

What happens if I execute this script at exactly the same split second?

Laravel says:

> Alternatively, you may use the lockForUpdate method. A "for update"
>   lock prevents the rows from being modified **or from being selected** with
>   another shared lock.

**Does the lockForUpdate prevent a read from happening at the same time, or does it only come in to affect when doing a following UPDATE to the row?**

Can I guarantee if a script is already reading from this row, then a concurrent script at the same millisecond will fail and WAIT for the transaction to release the lock before trying to run the code?

I haven't found a super clear answer anywhere, all examples are trying to update or insert. I just want to guard against a concurrent select.

Comment: I'm running concurrency test, and the lines following the SELECT seem to happen at the same millisecond. Which means that it isn't locking the row as expected?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but as there are no answers, here is my input. I've faced similar situation and after several T&E, finally got to lock the table records that are intended to be modified by only one exclusive transaction at a given time.

Probably not worthy of mention, is your table storage engine set to InnoDB? Because after several failed attempts, I discovered that my table storage engine was MyISAM.